# File extensions and MIME Types in .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, content-type, mime, file-extension

I want to get a MIME Content-Type from a given extension (preferably without accessing the physical file). I have seen some questions about this and the methods described to perform this can be resumed in:

1. Use [registry information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029740/get-a-mime-from-an-extention/1029796#1029796).
2. Use [urlmon.dll's FindMimeFromData](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/in-c-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature-not-th/58570#58570).
3. Use [IIS information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174888/asp-net-iis6-how-to-search-the-servers-mime-map/174988#174988).
4. Roll your own MIME mapping function. Based on [this table](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/conf/mime.types), for example.

I've been using no.1 for some time but I realized that the information provided by the registry is not consistent and depends on the software installed on the machine. Some extensions, like .zip don't use to have a Content-Type specified.

Solution no.2 forces me to have the file on disk in order to read the first bytes, which is something slow but may get good results.

The third method is based on Directory Services and all that stuff, which is something I don't like much because I have to add COM references and I'm not sure it's consistent between IIS6 and IIS7. Also, I don't know the performance of this method.

Finally, I didn't want to use my own table but at the end seems the best option if I want a decent performance and consistency of the results between platforms (even Mono).

Do you think there's a better option than using my own table or one of other described methods are better? What's your experience?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

It depends what you need the MIME type for. In general, for services (web apps, web service, etc.), it's advisable not to use a MIME list which is dependent on the OS settings, or only as fallback if you cannot find MIME information otherwise.

I think that this is also the reason why MS chose to put constant MIME types in their `System.Web.MimeMapping` class (unfortunately it's internal, for whatever reason).

Edit:

#### Wrapper (<= .NET 3.5)

```
public static class MimeExtensionHelper
{
    static object locker = new object();
    static object mimeMapping;
    static MethodInfo getMimeMappingMethodInfo;

    static MimeExtensionHelper()
    {
        Type mimeMappingType = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(HttpRuntime)).GetType("System.Web.MimeMapping");
        if (mimeMappingType == null)
            throw new SystemException("Couldnt find MimeMapping type");
        ConstructorInfo constructorInfo = mimeMappingType.GetConstructor(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null);
        if (constructorInfo == null)
            throw new SystemException("Couldnt find default constructor for MimeMapping");
        mimeMapping = constructorInfo.Invoke(null);
        if (mimeMapping == null)
            throw new SystemException("Couldnt find MimeMapping");
        getMimeMappingMethodInfo = mimeMappingType.GetMethod("GetMimeMapping", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
        if (getMimeMappingMethodInfo == null)
            throw new SystemException("Couldnt find GetMimeMapping method");
        if (getMimeMappingMethodInfo.ReturnType != typeof(string))
            throw new SystemException("GetMimeMapping method has invalid return type");
        if (getMimeMappingMethodInfo.GetParameters().Length != 1 && getMimeMappingMethodInfo.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType != typeof(string))
            throw new SystemException("GetMimeMapping method has invalid parameters");
    }
    public static string GetMimeType(string filename)
    {
        lock (locker)
            return (string)getMimeMappingMethodInfo.Invoke(mimeMapping, new object[] { filename });
    }
}
```

#### Wrapper (.NET 4.0)

```
public static class MimeExtensionHelper
    {
        static object locker = new object();
        static object mimeMapping;
        static MethodInfo getMimeMappingMethodInfo;

        static MimeExtensionHelper()
        {
            Type mimeMappingType = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(HttpRuntime)).GetType("System.Web.MimeMapping");
            if (mimeMappingType == null)
                throw new SystemException("Couldnt find MimeMapping type");            
            getMimeMappingMethodInfo = mimeMappingType.GetMethod("GetMimeMapping", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
            if (getMimeMappingMethodInfo == null)
                throw new SystemException("Couldnt find GetMimeMapping method");
            if (getMimeMappingMethodInfo.ReturnType != typeof(string))
                throw new SystemException("GetMimeMapping method has invalid return type");
            if (getMimeMappingMethodInfo.GetParameters().Length != 1 && getMimeMappingMethodInfo.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType != typeof(string))
                throw new SystemException("GetMimeMapping method has invalid parameters");
        }
        public static string GetMimeType(string filename)
        {
            lock (locker)
                return (string)getMimeMappingMethodInfo.Invoke(mimeMapping, new object[] { filename });
        }
    }
```

**.NET 4.5+**

No wrapper required, call the public method [`System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mimemapping.getmimemapping(v=vs.110).aspx) directly.

Comment: Interesting... didn't know that about the internal type, but seems revealing.

Comment: Added edits for .NET 4 support - seems like they removed the instance ctor and made **GetMimeMapping** method public.

Comment: Possibly worth noting that in .NET 4.5 this is fully public and doesn't need any reflection a la http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mimemapping.getmimemapping.aspx

Comment: @rudi_visser, thanks for the hint - finally MS noticed that this is not just needed for their own code. :)

Comment: Would you be able to provide the vb.net eqvalent of this, i'm having trouble converting it

Comment: For .jpeg it returns `application/octet-stream` which is not what I expected. I wanted `image/jpg`.

Comment: To follow up @Tymek, on my system it returns `application/octet-stream` for every type I can think of (js, gif, html, css, ico, xml, mp3, woff, etc).  Same results from linqpad and from a test page in ASP.NET.

Comment: @Tymek, @harpo: The `GetMimeMapping` function expects a file name, not just the extension.

Comment: var mimetype = System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping(filenamewithext) - This is awesome doesn't have to be filepath and this even won't access the file- it is logically takes last index of '.' and gets from library

Comment: @RudiVisser And looking at the sources, [`GetMimeMapping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mimemapping.getmimemapping.aspx) really just relies on [a static list](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/MimeMapping.cs,96).

Comment: @AtifAziz Indeed, but I'd be hoping that it is IIS-Aware in the case of ASP.NET Applications, so if custom MIME Types were added in the IIS Config for a specific site (or at any level really) they would be available to the application running there.

Comment: @AtifAziz Ah yes, [it does](http://referencesource.microsoft.com#System.Web/MimeMapping.cs,462)! Happy times.

Comment: @RudiVisser True, the static list seems to be a fallback case.

Comment: It's too bad `System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping` is missing some important types, e.g. `application/json` for `.json` files.

Answer (score 14):

I have combined all these approaches in my utility lib, except maybe no.3.
Btw, no.2 (urlmon.dll) doesn't require static file, it simply takes some bytes no matter where they had come from.
Here's my current class

```
namespace Components
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.IO;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Xml.Serialization;
    using Microsoft.Win32;

    public sealed class MimeExtensionHelper
    {
        private MimeExtensionHelper() { }

        /// <summary>Finds extension associated with specified mime type</summary>
        /// <param name="mimeType">mime type you search extension for, e.g.: "application/octet-stream"</param>
        /// <returns>most used extension, associated with provided type, e.g.: ".bin"</returns>
        public static string FindExtension(string mimeType)
        {
            return ExtensionTypes.GetExtension(mimeType);
        }

        /// <summary>Finds mime type using provided extension and/or file's binary content.</summary>
        /// <param name="file">Full file path</param>
        /// <param name="verifyFromContent">Should the file's content be examined to verify founded value.</param>
        /// <returns>mime type of file, e.g.: "application/octet-stream"</returns>
        public static string FindMime(string file,bool verifyFromContent)
        {
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(file);
            string mimeType = string.Empty;
            try
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(extension))
                    mimeType = ExtensionTypes.GetMimeType(extension);
                if (verifyFromContent
                    || (String.IsNullOrEmpty(mimeType) && File.Exists(file)))
                    mimeType = FindMimeByContent(file,mimeType);
            }
            catch { }
            return (mimeType ?? string.Empty).Trim();//"application/octet-stream"
        }

        /// <summary>Finds mime type for file using it's binary data.</summary>
        /// <param name="file">Full path to file.</param>
        /// <param name="proposedType">Optional. Expected file's type.</param>
        /// <returns>mime type, e.g.: "application/octet-stream"</returns>
        public static string FindMimeByContent(string file
            ,string proposedType)
        {
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(file);
            if (!fi.Exists)
                throw new FileNotFoundException(file);
            byte[] buf = new byte[Math.Min(4096L,fi.Length)];
            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(file))
                fs.Read(buf,0,buf.Length);
            return FindMimeByData(buf,proposedType);
        }

        /// <summary>Finds mime type for binary data.</summary>
        /// <param name="dataBytes">Binary data to examine.</param>
        /// <param name="mimeProposed">Optional. Expected mime type.</param>
        /// <returns>mime type, e.g.: "application/octet-stream"</returns>
        public static string FindMimeByData(byte[] dataBytes,string mimeProposed)
        {
            if (dataBytes == null || dataBytes.Length == 0)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("dataBytes");
            string mimeRet = String.Empty;
            IntPtr outPtr = IntPtr.Zero;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mimeProposed))
                mimeRet = mimeProposed;
            int result = FindMimeFromData(IntPtr.Zero
                ,null
                ,dataBytes
                ,dataBytes.Length
                ,String.IsNullOrEmpty(mimeProposed) ? null : mimeProposed
                ,0
                ,out outPtr
                ,0);
            if (result != 0)
                throw Marshal.GetExceptionForHR(result);
            if (outPtr != null && outPtr != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                mimeRet = Marshal.PtrToStringUni(outPtr);
                Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(outPtr);
            }
            return mimeRet;
        }

        [DllImport("urlmon.dll"
            ,CharSet = CharSet.Unicode
            ,ExactSpelling = true
            ,SetLastError = true)]
        static extern Int32 FindMimeFromData(IntPtr pBC
            ,[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] String pwzUrl
            ,[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray,ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.I1,SizeParamIndex = 3)] Byte[] pBuffer
            ,Int32 cbSize
            ,[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] String pwzMimeProposed
            ,Int32 dwMimeFlags
            ,out IntPtr ppwzMimeOut
            ,Int32 dwReserved);

        private static MimeTypeCollection _extensionTypes = null;
        private static MimeTypeCollection ExtensionTypes
        {
            get
            {
                if (_extensionTypes == null)
                    _extensionTypes = new MimeTypeCollection();
                return _extensionTypes;
            }
        }

        [Serializable]
        [XmlRoot(ElementName = "mimeTypes")]
        private class MimeTypeCollection : List<MimeTypeCollection.mimeTypeInfo>
        {
            private SortedList<string,string> _extensions;
            private SortedList<string,List<string>> _mimes;

            private void Init()
            {
                if (_extensions == null || _mimes == null
                    || _extensions.Count == 0 || _mimes.Count == 0)
                {
                    _extensions = new SortedList<string,string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                    _mimes = new SortedList<string,List<string>>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
                    foreach (var mime in this)
                    {
                        _mimes.Add(mime.MimeType,new List<string>(mime.Extensions));
                        foreach (string ext in mime.Extensions)
                            if (!_extensions.ContainsKey(ext))
                                _extensions.Add(ext,mime.MimeType);
                    }
                }
            }

            public String GetExtension(string type)
            {
                Init();
                return _mimes.ContainsKey(type) ? _mimes[type][0] : string.Empty;
            }

            public String GetMimeType(string extension)
            {
                Init();
                return _extensions.ContainsKey(extension) ? _extensions[extension] : string.Empty;
            }

        public MimeTypeCollection()
        {
            this.Add(new mimeTypeInfo("application/applixware",new List<string>(new[] { ".aw" })));
            this.Add(new mimeTypeInfo("application/atom+xml",new List<string>(new[] { ".atom" })));
            // ... Whole list from apache's site
            this.Add(new mimeTypeInfo("x-x509-ca-cert",new List<string>(new[] { ".cer" })));
            try
            {
                using (RegistryKey classesRoot = Registry.ClassesRoot)
                using (RegistryKey typeKey = classesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"MIME\Database\Content Type"))
                {
                    string[] subKeyNames = typeKey.GetSubKeyNames();
                    string extension = string.Empty;
                    foreach (string keyname in subKeyNames)
                    {
                        string trimmed = (keyname ?? string.Empty).Trim();
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(trimmed))
                            continue;
                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(GetExtension(trimmed)))
                            continue;
                        string subKey = "MIME\\Database\\Content Type\\" + trimmed;
                        using (RegistryKey curKey = classesRoot.OpenSubKey(subKey))
                        {
                            extension = (curKey.GetValue("Extension") as string ?? string.Empty).Trim();
                            if (extension.Length > 0)
                                this.Add(new mimeTypeInfo(trimmed
                                    ,new List<string>(new[] { extension })));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string s = ex.ToString();
            }
        }

        [Serializable]
        public class mimeTypeInfo
        {
            [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "mimeType")]
            public String MimeType { get; set; }

            [XmlElement("extension")]
            public List<String> Extensions { get; set; }

            public mimeTypeInfo(string mimeType,List<string> extensions)
            {
                MimeType = mimeType;
                Extensions = extensions;
            }

            public mimeTypeInfo() { }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 9):

The `System.Web.MimeMapping` has 3 versions - two version 4.0s (where one of these is internal), and then a version 2.0 which is also internal. As pointed out, there is a public version of the class in System.Web version 4.0 for the .NET 4.5 framework.

For RoadkillWiki I've basically reverse engineered it to save the bother of reflecting each time, the  Wiki's file handler tries to the use IIS/applicationhost.config by default, and then falls through to the MimeMapping class:

```
private string GetMimeType(string fileExtension, ServerManager serverManager)
{
    try
    {
        string mimeType = "text/plain";

        Microsoft.Web.Administration.Configuration config = serverManager.GetApplicationHostConfiguration();
        ConfigurationSection staticContentSection = config.GetSection("system.webServer/staticContent");
        ConfigurationElementCollection mimemaps = staticContentSection.GetCollection();

        ConfigurationElement element = mimemaps.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Attributes["fileExtension"].Value.ToString() == fileExtension);

        if (element != null)
            mimeType = element.Attributes["mimeType"].Value.ToString();

        return mimeType;
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        // Shared hosting won't have access to the applicationhost.config file
        return MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping("." +fileExtension);
    }
}
```

And MimeMapping:

```
public class MimeMapping
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string> ExtensionMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    static MimeMapping()
    {
        ExtensionMap.Add(".323", "text/h323");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".asx", "video/x-ms-asf");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".acx", "application/internet-property-stream");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".ai", "application/postscript");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".aif", "audio/x-aiff");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".aiff", "audio/aiff");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".axs", "application/olescript");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".aifc", "audio/aiff");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".asr", "video/x-ms-asf");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".avi", "video/x-msvideo");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".asf", "video/x-ms-asf");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".au", "audio/basic");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".application", "application/x-ms-application");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".bin", "application/octet-stream");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".bas", "text/plain");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".bcpio", "application/x-bcpio");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".bmp", "image/bmp");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".cdf", "application/x-cdf");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".cat", "application/vndms-pkiseccat");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".crt", "application/x-x509-ca-cert");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".c", "text/plain");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".css", "text/css");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".cer", "application/x-x509-ca-cert");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".crl", "application/pkix-crl");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".cmx", "image/x-cmx");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".csh", "application/x-csh");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".cod", "image/cis-cod");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".cpio", "application/x-cpio");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".clp", "application/x-msclip");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".crd", "application/x-mscardfile");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".deploy", "application/octet-stream");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".dll", "application/x-msdownload");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".dot", "application/msword");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".doc", "application/msword");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".dvi", "application/x-dvi");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".dir", "application/x-director");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".dxr", "application/x-director");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".der", "application/x-x509-ca-cert");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".dib", "image/bmp");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".dcr", "application/x-director");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".disco", "text/xml");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".exe", "application/octet-stream");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".etx", "text/x-setext");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".evy", "application/envoy");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".eml", "message/rfc822");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".eps", "application/postscript");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".flr", "x-world/x-vrml");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".fif", "application/fractals");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".gtar", "application/x-gtar");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".gif", "image/gif");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".gz", "application/x-gzip");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".hta", "application/hta");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".htc", "text/x-component");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".htt", "text/webviewhtml");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".h", "text/plain");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".hdf", "application/x-hdf");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".hlp", "application/winhlp");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".html", "text/html");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".htm", "text/html");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".hqx", "application/mac-binhex40");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".isp", "application/x-internet-signup");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".iii", "application/x-iphone");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".ief", "image/ief");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".ivf", "video/x-ivf");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".ins", "application/x-internet-signup");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".ico", "image/x-icon");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".jpg", "image/jpeg");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".jfif", "image/pjpeg");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".jpe", "image/jpeg");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".jpeg", "image/jpeg");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".js", "application/x-javascript");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".lsx", "video/x-la-asf");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".latex", "application/x-latex");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".lsf", "video/x-la-asf");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".manifest", "application/x-ms-manifest");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".mhtml", "message/rfc822");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".mny", "application/x-msmoney");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".mht", "message/rfc822");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".mid", "audio/mid");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".mpv2", "video/mpeg");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".man", "application/x-troff-man");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".mvb", "application/x-msmediaview");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".mpeg", "video/mpeg");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".m3u", "audio/x-mpegurl");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".mdb", "application/x-msaccess");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".mpp", "application/vnd.ms-project");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".m1v", "video/mpeg");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".mpa", "video/mpeg");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".me", "application/x-troff-me");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".m13", "application/x-msmediaview");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".movie", "video/x-sgi-movie");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".m14", "application/x-msmediaview");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".mpe", "video/mpeg");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".mp2", "video/mpeg");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".mov", "video/quicktime");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".mp3", "audio/mpeg");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".mpg", "video/mpeg");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".ms", "application/x-troff-ms");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".nc", "application/x-netcdf");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".nws", "message/rfc822");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".oda", "application/oda");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".ods", "application/oleobject");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".pmc", "application/x-perfmon");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".p7r", "application/x-pkcs7-certreqresp");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".p7b", "application/x-pkcs7-certificates");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".p7s", "application/pkcs7-signature");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".pmw", "application/x-perfmon");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".ps", "application/postscript");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".p7c", "application/pkcs7-mime");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".pbm", "image/x-portable-bitmap");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".ppm", "image/x-portable-pixmap");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".pub", "application/x-mspublisher");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".pnm", "image/x-portable-anymap");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".pml", "application/x-perfmon");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".p10", "application/pkcs10");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".pfx", "application/x-pkcs12");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".p12", "application/x-pkcs12");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".pdf", "application/pdf");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".pps", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".p7m", "application/pkcs7-mime");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".pko", "application/vndms-pkipko");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".ppt", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".pmr", "application/x-perfmon");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".pma", "application/x-perfmon");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".pot", "application/vnd.ms-powerpoint");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".prf", "application/pics-rules");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".pgm", "image/x-portable-graymap");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".qt", "video/quicktime");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".ra", "audio/x-pn-realaudio");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".rgb", "image/x-rgb");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".ram", "audio/x-pn-realaudio");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".rmi", "audio/mid");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".ras", "image/x-cmu-raster");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".roff", "application/x-troff");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".rtf", "application/rtf");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".rtx", "text/richtext");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".sv4crc", "application/x-sv4crc");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".spc", "application/x-pkcs7-certificates");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".setreg", "application/set-registration-initiation");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".snd", "audio/basic");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".stl", "application/vndms-pkistl");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".setpay", "application/set-payment-initiation");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".stm", "text/html");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".shar", "application/x-shar");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".sh", "application/x-sh");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".sit", "application/x-stuffit");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".spl", "application/futuresplash");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".sct", "text/scriptlet");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".scd", "application/x-msschedule");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".sst", "application/vndms-pkicertstore");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".src", "application/x-wais-source");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".sv4cpio", "application/x-sv4cpio");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".tex", "application/x-tex");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".tgz", "application/x-compressed");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".t", "application/x-troff");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".tar", "application/x-tar");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".tr", "application/x-troff");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".tif", "image/tiff");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".txt", "text/plain");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".texinfo", "application/x-texinfo");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".trm", "application/x-msterminal");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".tiff", "image/tiff");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".tcl", "application/x-tcl");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".texi", "application/x-texinfo");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".tsv", "text/tab-separated-values");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".ustar", "application/x-ustar");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".uls", "text/iuls");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".vcf", "text/x-vcard");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".wps", "application/vnd.ms-works");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".wav", "audio/wav");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".wrz", "x-world/x-vrml");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".wri", "application/x-mswrite");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".wks", "application/vnd.ms-works");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".wmf", "application/x-msmetafile");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".wcm", "application/vnd.ms-works");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".wrl", "x-world/x-vrml");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".wdb", "application/vnd.ms-works");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".wsdl", "text/xml");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".xml", "text/xml");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".xlm", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".xaf", "x-world/x-vrml");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".xla", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".xls", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".xof", "x-world/x-vrml");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".xlt", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".xlc", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".xsl", "text/xml");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".xbm", "image/x-xbitmap");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".xlw", "application/vnd.ms-excel");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".xpm", "image/x-xpixmap");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".xwd", "image/x-xwindowdump");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".xsd", "text/xml");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".z", "application/x-compress");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".zip", "application/x-zip-compressed");
        ExtensionMap.Add(".*", "application/octet-stream");
    }

    public static string GetMimeMapping(string fileExtension)
    {
        if (ExtensionMap.ContainsKey(fileExtension))
            return ExtensionMap[fileExtension];
        else
            return ExtensionMap[".*"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I've written a program to fetch and convert the Apache mime.types file to a C# `Dictionary<string, string>` keyed by file extension. It's here:

https://github.com/cymen/ApacheMimeTypesToDotNet

The actual output is this file:

https://github.com/cymen/ApacheMimeTypesToDotNet/blob/master/ApacheMimeTypes.cs

Hopefully someone else finds it useful too!

Answer (score 1):

Nisus - would you be willing to post the entire source code for your utility somewhere?  that would really be helpful.  thanks!

Never mind....

I edited the apache definition file to only contain entries with defined extensions, then extended the code to load in the types/extensions from the text file at run time.  Not elegant perhaps but sure beats creating/maintaining 630 lines of source code for the mime types.

[in the constructor for MimeTypeCollection instead of this stuff:
this.Add(new mimeTypeInfo("application/applixware",new List(new[] { ".aw" })));]

```
        // import mime/extension definition list to facilitate maintenance
    string dir = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    using (TextReader streamReader = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(dir, "MimeDefinitions.txt")))
    {
      string input;
      while ((input = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
        if (input.Substring(0, 1) != "#")
        {
          // text line format ::= [contenttype]<tab>[space delimited list of extensions, without dot]
          string contentType = input.Group("0\t1");
          string extensionList = input.Group("1\t1");
          string[] extensions = extensionList.Split(" ".ToCharArray());
          List<string> extensionSet = new List<string>();
          foreach (string term in extensions)
          {
            extensionSet.Add("."+term);
          }
          this.Add(new mimeTypeInfo(contentType, extensionSet));
        }
      }
    }
```

I also found that the Init() method would be called and the _extensions and _mime members would not be completely initialized so I changed it to read:

```
if (_extensions == null || _mimes == null || _mimes.Count != this.Count)
```

Anyway, I now how a class that can handle the external defs and local registry I needed.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I also found that the Init() method would be called and the _extensions and _mime members would not be completely initialized so I changed it to read, and the best way is, remove call GetExtension in constructor from MimeTypeCollection:

```
        public MimeTypeCollection()
        {
            this.Add(new mimeTypeInfo("application/applixware", new List<string>(new[] { ".aw" })));
            this.Add(new mimeTypeInfo("application/atom+xml", new List<string>(new[] { ".atom" })));
            // ... Whole list from apache's site
            this.Add(new mimeTypeInfo("x-x509-ca-cert", new List<string>(new[] { ".cer" })));
            try
            {
                using (RegistryKey classesRoot = Registry.ClassesRoot)
                using (RegistryKey typeKey = classesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"MIME\Database\Content Type"))
                {
                    string[] subKeyNames = typeKey.GetSubKeyNames();
                    string extension = string.Empty;
                    foreach (string keyname in subKeyNames)
                    {
                        string trimmed = (keyname ?? string.Empty).Trim();
                        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(trimmed))
                            continue;
                        if (this.Exists(mime => mime.MimeType == trimmed))
                            continue;
                        //if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(GetExtension(trimmed)))
                        //  continue;
                        string subKey = "MIME\\Database\\Content Type\\" + trimmed;
                        using (RegistryKey curKey = classesRoot.OpenSubKey(subKey))
                        {
                            extension = (curKey.GetValue("Extension") as string ?? string.Empty).Trim();
                            if (extension.Length > 0)
                                this.Add(new mimeTypeInfo(trimmed
                                        , new List<string>(new[] { extension })));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string s = ex.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would just like to caution you against retrieving the Mime / content type of a file without validating it against the actual content of the file, as it could pose a serious security risk to your system and users.

Although there are valid use cases for something like this, attackers can potentially attack your system or use it as a mechanism to propagate malicious files to other users, by disguising executables or scripts as other, non-suspect file types.

It is advisable that you seriously consider sandboxing and performing deep content inspection on uploaded files before continuing to process it (or making it available for download).