# Get the MimeType(Content Type) of a file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, mime

How will I get the Mime Type or Content Type of a Specific file through its file extension? 
This program is developed in MVC3 Razor Syntax, the code looks like this:

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(file))
            return File(file, "application/pdf", id);
        else
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

I want to change the application/pdf to a dynamic value such that it would supply the MIME type through the id or the filename that is sent to the controller.

Comment: [c# - Using .NET, how can you find the mime type of a file based on the file signature not the extension - Stack Overflow][1] 

How about FindMimeFromData API?

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature

Comment: File extensions do not map to MIME types 1:1.

Comment: Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612767/file-extensions-and-mime-types-in-net

Comment: In .Net 4.5 you could use `System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping()`

Answer (score 1):

You could look up the registry value at `HKCR\<file extension>\Content Type`.  This value doesn't exist for all file types, but probably does for all the file types you're interested in.