# PowerShell: Possible to Determine a File's MIME Type?

Tags: .net, powershell

Is it possible for PowerShell to determine what a given file's type is? For example, if I pass it a path of `C:\Foo.zip`, can I have it determine that the file at that path is, in fact, a zip file and not something else?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PowerShell, like rest of the Windows operating system, merely guesses the file type based on the extension.

However, there are third-party file type guesser programs out there, ones that actually look at the contents of the file.

There is a [truly excellent answer to this question over on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/274734/is-there-a-tool-that-can-determine-the-file-type-from-containing-data). Top recommendations include [File for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm) and [TrID](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html).

Answer (score 12):

If you have .NET 4.5+, you can use the static method [`System.Web.MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mimemapping.getmimemapping(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
> Add-Type -AssemblyName "System.Web"
> [System.Web.MimeMapping]::GetMimeMapping("C:\foo.zip")
application/x-zip-compressed
```

Credit goes to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1612794/113116) to a similar question about .NET.

---

Edit: Misread the question. `GetMimeMapping` returns the MIME type by extension, it doesn't analyze the contents.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to be supported in PowerShell 6 anymore.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the mime types from the registry.  Unfortunately the HKEY_CURRENT_USER hive isn't auto-mapped as a drive so you'll have to put a check in for that first.

```
function Get-MimeType()
{
  param($extension = $null);
  $mimeType = $null;
  if ( $null -ne $extension )
  {
    $drive = Get-PSDrive HKCR -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue;
    if ( $null -eq $drive )
    {
      $drive = New-PSDrive -Name HKCR -PSProvider Registry -Root HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
    }
    $mimeType = (Get-ItemProperty HKCR:$extension)."Content Type";
  }
  $mimeType;
}
```

Here's an example usage

```
PS> Get-MimeType -extension .zip
application/x-zip-compressed
```

-Joe

Comment: This doesn't actually test the contents of the target file, it simply reads the extension and looks up the file type relationship from the OS.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ext = ".exe"
$null = New-PSDrive HKCR Registry HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT -ea 0
$mime = (gp HKCR:$ext)."Content Type"
write-host $ext $mime
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your answer (tell us _what_ the issue is, and _how_ this code fixes that issue). Code-only answers are less educational and of limited use.

Comment: You should give more context/explanation for the code, especially since there are already several high-quality answers. Please read the site [tour] as well as [answer].