# How to remove some words from all text file in a folder by powershell?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

I have a situation that I need to remove some words from all text file in a folder.
I know how to do that only in 1 file, but I need to do it automatically for all text files in that folder. I got no idea at all how to do it in powershell.
The name of the files are random.

Please help.

This is the code

---

$txt = get-content c:\work\test\01.i

$txt[0] = $txt[0] -replace '-'

$txt[$txt.length - 1 ] = $txt[$txt.length - 1 ] -replace '-'

$txt | set-content c:\work\test\01.i

---

Basicly it jsut removes a "-" from first line and last line, but i need to do this on all files in the folder.

Comment: I posted in the duplicate question YOU created(duplicate questions is bad btw). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442229/

Answer (score 1):

```
Get-ChildItem c:\yourfolder -Filter *.txt | Foreach-Object{
   ... your code goes here ...
   ... you can access the current file name via $_.FullName ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full working example:

```
Get-ChildItem c:\yourdirectory -Filter *.txt | Foreach-Object{
(Get-Content $_.FullName) | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "what you want to replace", "what to replace it with"} | 
Set-Content $_.FullName
}
```

Now for a quick explanation:

- Get-ChildItem with a Filter: gets all items ending in .txt
- 1st ForEach-Object: will perform the commands within the curly brackets
- Get-Content $_.FullName: grabs the name of the .txt file
- 2nd ForEach-Object: will perform the replacement of text within the file
- Set-Content $_.FullName: replaces the original file with the new file containing the changes

Important Note: -replace is working with a regular expression so if your string of text has any special characters

Answer (score 0):

something like this ?

```
ls c:\temp\*.txt | %{ $newcontent=(gc $_) -replace "test","toto"  |sc $_ }
```

Comment: how to only remove a "-" from first line and last line?

Comment: $txt = get-content c:\work\test\01.i

$txt[0] = $txt[0] -replace '-'

$txt[$txt.length - 1 ] = $txt[$txt.length - 1 ] -replace '-'

$txt | set-content c:\work\test\01.i

Answer (score 0):

```
$files = get-item c:\temp\*.txt
foreach ($file in $files){(Get-Content $file) | ForEach-Object {$_ -replace 'ur word','new word'}  | Out-File $file}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Get-Childitem` to filter for the files you want to modify.  Per [response to previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11698572/4446881) "Powershell, like Windows, uses the extension of the file to determine the filetype."

Also:
You will replace ALL "-" with "" on the first and last lines, using what your example shows, IF you use this instead:

```
 $txt[0] = $txt[0] -replace '-', ''
 $txt[$txt.length - 1 ] = $txt[$txt.length - 1 ] -replace '-', ''
```