# How to remove words from all text files in a folder?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-ise

I have a code like this:

```
$txt = get-content c:\work\test\01.i

$txt[0] = $txt[0] -replace '-'

$txt[$txt.length - 1 ] = $txt[$txt.length - 1 ] -replace '-'

$txt | set-content c:\work\test\01.i
```

It just removes a `-` from first line and last line in a text file, but I need to do this for all text files in the directory tree which contains over 5k text files. how should I modify this code?

All name of text files are random.

I need to do this in powershell.

Its a directory tree, under c:\work\test there will be more lvl of sub-folders then contains all text files.

Please help . thanks

Comment: Then you want to be able to obtain all files from a specified folder and loop through each one. You might be able to figure it out from this: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/Copy-all-SharePoint-Files-0999c53f

Comment: You need some way of telling what files to touch. Fileextension, name-pattern.  I provided an answer you can modify for your pattern. Ex. if the folder where they are, ONLY contains these files, then you could just remove `-Filter *.i` in my answer. We can't touch all files, because then it will try to open .exe files and sh*t and it will get ugly :P

Comment: Yes Blitzcrank from LOL @_@

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get all files by file extension or something a pattern and loop through them. Lets say it's all the  files with `.i` extension. Try:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "c:\work\test" -Filter *.i -Recurse | where { !$_.PSIsContainer } | % { 
    $txt = Get-Content $_.FullName; 
    $txt[0] = $txt[0] -replace '-'; 
    $txt[$txt.length - 1 ] = $txt[$txt.length - 1 ] -replace '-';
    $txt | Set-Content $_.FullName
    }
```

Comment: oh, 1 issue, how to run this on a directory tee structure? This works if only there are files under c:\work\test, what if there are folders under c:\work\test\  and text files will be under that subfolder and so on?