# Powershell get files older than x days and move them

Tags: pdf, powershell, csv

I am sure this might have been asked a million times before. I am very new to Power Shell and would like to ask if I am doing this right.

In the directory, we have many files types. What I am trying to accomplish is to move only PDF files that are older than one month. To not even touch the other file extensions. The extensions in the folder are:

pdf, xml, csv

I have searched the forums prior to asking. This is what I have so far.

`get-childitem -path \\server\folder -include "*.pdf" -exclude "*.xml,*.csv" | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (get-date).AddDays(-31)} | move-item -destination \\server\folder\folder2`

One question though, how would you handle an exclude if there is no file extension?

Thanks for your time and patience with this noob!

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to use "where" to test the extension as get-childitem does this for you. Although I would use the filter parameter (2nd positional parameter) in the case of a single extension to search for e.g.:

```
$date = (get-date).AddDays(-31)
get-childitem \\server\folder *.pdf | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $date} | 
    move-item -destination \\server\folder\folder2
```

Btw using the filter parameter is also faster which maybe important when searching a network share.

Comment: I saw that online about the -filter switch. Power Shell is a lot better than DOS! I am re-writing all our DOS scripts into Power Shell. Power Shell seems to be a lot easier for me. Thanks for the help.

Comment: This script seems to take every file modified within the last 31 says instead of before.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to add `$_.Extension -eq ".pdf"` to your `where-object` block so that you only grab those extensions.

```
get-childitem -path \\server\folder  | where-object {
$_.extension -eq ".pdf" -and ($_.LastWriteTime -gt (get-date).AddDays(-31))} | move-item -destination C:\test\test
```

Also, if you want files older than one month, your date comparison needs to be -lt and not -gt

```
get-childitem -path \\server\folder  | where-object {
$_.extension -eq ".pdf" -and ($_.LastWriteTime -lt (get-date).AddDays(-31))} | move-item -destination C:\test\test
```

Comment: I understand that -gt is greater than? what does -lt mean? thanks for the extension var. didnt know about it. I appreciate your help.

Comment: No problem.  -lt is "Less Than".  The older a timestamp, the less it is.  So you want files that are less than a date 31 days ago.  Using -gt here will only grab files that have been written in the last 31 days.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to specify the -Name flag and use  wildcard for filename:

```
get-childitem -path \\server\folder -name "*.pdf" | where-object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (get-date).AddDays(-31)} | move-item -destination \\server\folder\folder2
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand your last question, but if you have pdf files with no extension, see [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698525/powershell-possible-to-determine-a-files-mime-type).

I think something like that can help you. The `file.exe` ([download](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/file.htm)) showing the mime-type of the files, which is something like `PDF document, version 1.6`, depending the pdf file version.

```
 gci . | ? { (file.exe -b $_) -match "pdf" }
```