# PowerShell script to move files from one location to another. Only files which are more than 5 days old

Tags: powershell-4.0

How to create a powershell script that moves files from one location to another specifying that any file that is 5 days old does not move?

Used Move-Item to move files from one location to another, but I need to move files which are more than 5 days old.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell get files older than x days and move them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246497/powershell-get-files-older-than-x-days-and-move-them)

Answer (score 0):

I think this pipeline should works for you

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Downloads -File | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -lt (Get-Date).AddDays(-5)} | Move-Item -PipelineVariable $_ -Destination C:\button
```