# find mime types for newly added extensions

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029740/get-a-mime-from-an-extention) its possible to get the "default" IIS mime types from HKEY_Classes_Root. 
However when I register a new type I cannot find the entry - does anyone know how I get read all IIS registered mime types progamatically ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question but the answer posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174888/asp-net-iis6-how-to-search-the-servers-mime-map) (shown below) resolves this for both IIS 6 & 7

```
         NameValueCollection map = new NameValueCollection();
            using (DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("IIS://localhost/MimeMap"))
            {
                PropertyValueCollection properties = entry.Properties["MimeMap"];
                Type t = properties[0].GetType();

                foreach (object property in properties)
                {
                    BindingFlags f = BindingFlags.GetProperty;
                    string ext = t.InvokeMember("Extension", f, null, property, null) as String;
                    string mime = t.InvokeMember("MimeType", f, null, property, null) as String;
                    map.Add(ext, mime);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have to add it in IIS.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608(WS.10).aspx

Update

You could try the DirectoryServices API:

```
public static string GetMimeTypeFromExtension(string extension)
{
    using (DirectoryEntry mimeMap = 
           new DirectoryEntry("IIS://Localhost/MimeMap"))
    {
        PropertyValueCollection propValues = mimeMap.Properties["MimeMap"];

        foreach (object value in propValues)
        {
                IISOle.IISMimeType mimeType = (IISOle.IISMimeType)value;

                if (extension == mimeType.Extension)
                {
                        return mimeType.MimeType;
                }
        }

        return null;

    }
}
```

[Can I setup an IIS MIME type in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234526/can-i-setup-an-iis-mime-type-in-net/234613#234613)

Comment: sorry - how does this help me find the already registered types?

Comment: Programmatically? From IIS Manager? From the registry? Please be more specific.

Comment: apologies - not very clear. Need to find the registered types programatically as in the linked question.

Comment: What version of IIS? My updated answer has a sample that should work in IIS6.

Comment: needs to be able to support iis6 & 7 - I've already tried this method and it doesn't work for iis 7. The registry method works for both, but not for any newly added types