# Programmatically determine if code is running under IIS Express

Tags: c#, iis, iis-express

I am not sure this is even possible, but I am hoping for a clue as to determine if the code that is currently executing is running under IIS Express. My best approximation so far, which is incredibly hackish and will certainly fail/break at some point:

```
bool IsExpress = 
  Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_SOFTWARE"] == "Microsoft-IIS/7.5"
  && Int32.Parse(Request.ServerVariables["INSTANCE_ID"]) > 1000000000;
```

Certainly there has to be a better way. My examination of the Application, Server and Request objects didn't seem to reveal anything that might provide better insight. Perhaps I just need to look at some other object?

**Update:**

I am really curious if there is a way to detect this - it is really academic at this point I don't have a burning need to use it. The original question stands. But in the spirit of responding to the comments, specifically I am interested in answering a criticism from another question/answer on this site: [How to search the server's MIME map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/174888/asp-net-iis6-how-to-search-the-servers-mime-map/2240821#224082). The criticism is that the posted answer does not work for IIS Express, only traditional IIS instances. IIS Express stores the MIME configuration in the applicationhost.config XML file and I would like to update that answer to provide a way to return that information for IIS Express as well. I could certainly just add some code that grabs the appropriate value from the XML (Yay for LINQ to XML!) but I would really like to make it smarter. To be clear, I don't need help parsing that file - just something more elegant in trying to detect if code is currently executing in the IIS Express engine.

**Update 2:**

IIS 8.0 Express Beta was [released this week](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/robert_mcmurray/archive/2012/03/05/microsoft-iis-8-0-express-beta-is-released.aspx), and it further goes to show that the approach in my question is brittle and will break. While it isn't a deal breaker to target a specific version, it would be nice to account for that and try to ensure the code will work with at least the known versions today.

Comment: what is your goal ? why do want to detect this (perhaps there is some other way to achieve your goal) ?

Comment: If it is running in IIS Express, what do you want to handle differently? Maybe that's the question you need to ask rather than how to detect IIS Express. "How do I do ____ instead of _____ when running in debug?," for example.

Comment: The desire is centered around examining some configuration elements - using DirectoryEntry("IIS:/localhost/W3SVC/") vs. parsing the XML in applicationhost.config that controls IIS Express.

Comment: Again, what exactly is your goal? Why should the application be aware of the hosting environment?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Would checking the current process name do the trick?

```
bool isExpress = 
  String.Compare(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName,"iisexpress") == 0;
```

Normal IIS runs under `w3wp.exe` from memory.

Comment: It's `w3wp` for IIS 7.5 -- but Im not sure about different versions of IIS. I know it's something different for the real old versions of IIS...

Comment: @debracey yes for older versions it will be `aspnet_wp.exe`.

Comment: The only potential issue I have encountered with this approach is that the System.Diagnostics.Process class requires Full Trust. Otherwise is seems to be working like a charm.

Comment: I tested the code and should be changed to:
bool isExpress =          String.Compare(Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName,"iisexpress") == 0;

Answer (score 3):

Oran Dennison's answer doesn't work for me any more with dotnet core.

I extended it by first creating a method that can get the parent process:

```
/// <summary>
/// A utility class to determine a process parent.
/// </summary>
/// <remarks>
/// From https://stackoverflow.com/a/3346055/240845
/// </remarks>
public static class ParentProcessUtilities
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the parent process.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="process">The process to get the parent of</param>
    /// <returns>The parent process.</returns>
    public static Process Parent(this Process process)
    {
        return GetParentProcess(process.Handle);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the parent process of the current process.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>An instance of the Process class.</returns>
    public static Process GetParentProcess()
    {
        return Process.GetCurrentProcess().Parent();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the parent process of a specified process.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="handle">The process handle.</param>
    /// <returns>The parent process.</returns>
    public static Process GetParentProcess(IntPtr handle)
    {
        ProcessInformation pbi = new ProcessInformation();

        // Note, according to Microsoft, this usage of NtQueryInformationProcess is 
        // unsupported and may change
        int status = NtQueryInformationProcess(
            handle, 0, ref pbi, Marshal.SizeOf(pbi), out _);
        if (status != 0)
        {
            throw new Win32Exception(status);
        }

        try
        {
            return Process.GetProcessById(pbi.InheritedFromUniqueProcessId.ToInt32());
        }
        catch (ArgumentException)
        {
            // not found
            return null;
        }
    }

    [DllImport("ntdll.dll")]
    private static extern int NtQueryInformationProcess(
        IntPtr processHandle, int processInformationClass,
        ref ProcessInformation processInformation, int processInformationLength, 
        out int returnLength);

    /// <summary>
    /// Used in the NtQueryInformationProcess call.
    /// </summary>
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct ProcessInformation
    {
        // These members must match PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION
        internal IntPtr Reserved1;
        internal IntPtr PebBaseAddress;
        internal IntPtr Reserved2_0;
        internal IntPtr Reserved2_1;
        internal IntPtr UniqueProcessId;
        internal IntPtr InheritedFromUniqueProcessId;

    }
}
```

Then, you can do something like:

```
public bool IsUnderIisExpress()
{
    var currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
    if (string.CompareOrdinal(currentProcess.ProcessName, "iisexpress") == 0)
    {
       return true;
    }

    var parentProcess = currentProcess.Parent();
    if (string.CompareOrdinal(parentProcess.ProcessName, "iisexpress") == 0
        || string.CompareOrdinal(parentProcess.ProcessName, "VSIISExeLauncher") == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: FYI `IWebHostBuilder.UseIIS()` (https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c85baf8db0c72ae8e68643029d514b2e737c9fae/src/Servers/IIS/IIS/src/WebHostBuilderIISExtensions.cs#L31) checks if `aspnetcorev2_inprocess.dll` has been loaded in this process.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind dropping into COM level APIs, you could use the IIS Version Manager API

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg418429.aspx

There is some discussion about how this has been used in this SO Post: [Starting and stopping IIS Express programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772092/starting-and-stopping-iis-express-programmatically)  -- not exactly what you want, but they do discuss using the API.

Edit: I should add that I haven't tried this myself but it seems promising, good luck!

Comment: I looked into this API but I had two reservations: One it is flagged as "not intended to be used directly from your code" - not a deal breaker but not encouraging either. Two I am not sure how (or even if you can) connect the currently executing code to an instance returned from the API. Maybe by matching URLs or something.

Comment: Not sure what you're getting at -- but what I would do is pull the IIS version into your code (into your own managed `enum` maybe) when the application pool starts up, then just store that in a static variable -- don't go off querying the COM API every time. The server type obviously can't change without restarting your app.

Comment: If I new up the IISVersionManager class, I can get a listing of IIS instances available on the machine but I have no way of mapping that IISVersion interface to the code that is executing inside of an IIS instance. I really don't see how this COM API helps me know if code that is currently running is inside IIS Express or not - not just that IIS Express is available. Maybe a code sample would help clarify what you are suggesting?

Comment: Oh OK - yeah - that's an excellent point... back to the drawing board

Answer (score 2):

Can we not try and see if one or more [limitation of IIS Express](http://www.techulator.com/resources/3119-Limitations-IIS-Developer-Express-compared-full.aspx) works or not, if it works it is not IIS Express. Example IIS Express does not support sharepoint services

Comment: Could you please share which of those specific (or other) limitations you think you could reliably test for?

Comment: some sort of query, say environment variables %IISBin% would be a good hint? or query share point service and if the result is unsupported-exception  we know we are on IIS Express

Comment: Testing for %IIS_BIN% may work, it looks like only IIS Express sets that variable. The only gotcha being that the EnvironmentPermission class can be set to deny access to those variables. I have no clue what you mean by "query for share point service" - SharePoint is a product you can install, not something native to IIS.