# How can my code find if it's running inside IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, iis

My C# code may be running inside an MVC3 application under IIS (currently 7.5, but I'd like to not depend on a specific version) or elsewhere.

Looks like one way to know that code is running under IIS is [to check the current process name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9578461/57428), but this approach depends on having a filename string hardcoded.

Is there some programmatic way to detect my code is running under IIS not depending on IIS version?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Have a look at the [HostingEnvironment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.aspx) class, especially the [IsHosted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.ishosted.aspx) method.

This will tell you if you are being hosted in an [ApplicationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.applicationmanager.aspx), which will tell you if you are being hosted by ASP.NET.

Strictly, it will not tell you that you are running under IIS but I think this actually meets your needs better.

Example code:

```
// Returns the file-system path for a given path.
public static string GetMappedPath(string path)
{
    if (HostingEnvironment.IsHosted)
    {
        if (!Path.IsPathRooted(path))
        {
            // We are about to call MapPath, so need to ensure that 
            // we do not pass an absolute path.
            // 
            // We use HostingEnvironment.MapPath, rather than 
            // Server.MapPath, to allow this method to be used
            // in application startup. Server.MapPath calls 
            // HostingEnvironment.MapPath internally.
            return HostingEnvironment.MapPath(path);
        }
        else {
            return path;
        }
    }
    else 
    {
        throw new ApplicationException (
                "I'm not in an ASP.NET hosted environment :-(");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Have a look at the [ServiceController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.serviceprocess.servicecontroller.aspx) class. The service name will still be hardcoded, but the chances of the service changing name are relatively low.

You could also use `netstat -ab` to find out what is running on the port 80.

Comment: Just because IIS is running on port 80 doesn't mean his application is being hosted in IIS. The converse is also true - IIS could be running on any other port (e.g. 8080)

Comment: True. That's why the ServiceController class is recommended.

Comment: All ServiceController can do is tell you whether the IIS service is running, not whether the current code is running in that IIS.